# Geometry in Vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Let
${A} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} & -\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5} \\ \sin \frac{2 \pi}{5} & \cos \frac{2 \pi}{5} \end{pmatrix}$
and
${B} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Let $S$ be the set of all matrices that can be generated from taking products of ${A}$ and ${B}$, in any order. For example, the matrix ${A}^2 {B} ^4 {B}$ is in the set $S$. Find the number of distinct elements in $S$.

I am trying to solve this geometrically, but I am having trouble with that.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  For a geometric perspective, note that $A$ rotates vectors $(a,b)$ counterclockwise thorugh $2\pi /5$ radians and $B$ reflects them in the $x$-axis.

Comment: this generates the dihedral group $D_5$ of order $10?$

Answer (score 0):

A simple heuristic might be to notice that applying $B$ twice sets everything back to where it started, and applying $A$ five times will do the same (if it helps, picture the effect of these transformations on a regular pentagon centered at the origin). What might be a good guess for the number of unique combinations of both?

You can later support this guess with the property (for this pair of matrices) $AB = BA^{-1}$, which will allow you to simply enumerate elements: $A^tB^s,\, s,t = 0,1,2,\dots$.

To illustrate the property I have referenced, take this regular pentagon, and apply $B$ once:

[image: s]

and now $A$:

[image: rs]

The final result corresponds to applying the transformation $AB$. Now for $BA^{-1}$. Begin with the original pentagon, and apply $A^{-1}$:

[image: r4]

finally, apply $B$:

[image: sr4]

The end result, as you can see, is the same as $AB$. To prove it rigorously though, you should verify $AB = BA^{-1}$ algebraically.

Comment: GPerez - What program do you use to draw your lovely figures with?

Comment: @omegadot Geogebra, a lovely program itself. You can download it for free.